# Java gui frame overlapping

Tags: java, dialog, applet, frame

I have an applet which has two buttons on it:

When we click **Button1** a Frame is opened.
When we click **Button2** a Dialog (which is a child the new frame) is presented.

Now suppose if when we click on **Button1** then the new frame that is opened is now positioned behind my applet and not completely aligned with it (not minimized)

Now, when I press **Button2** the Dialog that pops up is in front of my applet, but when I click on the header of the dialog, then both the applet and frame are brought forward (they both get displayed simultaneously).

So I basically want to have just the applet behind the dialog whenever it is clicked (leaving the Frame in the background)

Comment: We'll need to see some code to help you out here

Comment: *"Applet. ..a Frame gets open.. a Dialog(which is a child of new frame).."*  Don't open frames from an applet!  It is a recipe for disaster, as evidenced by (what it seems is) the current focus problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `frame.setVisible(false);` in **Button2**'s ActionListener.